# The Debug does not show output on the terminal

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

When I try to debug the Hello World in Microsoft Visual Studio Code, it did not print "Hello World" on the Terminal. How can I to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Debug console tab next to Terminal.